# Displaying admin navbar options according to permissions with NodeJS and React

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm considering using an admin navbar that only displays options for which the user has access permissions, but there is many way to do it and I was wondering what is the best to do so.

I'm hesitating between 2 methods, both has the same base

```js
router.get('/admin/some_page', async (req, res, next) => {
    const perms = await Database.getPerms(UID);
    //...
});
```

But now, should I build the navbar on server side and add it in the HTML file
Or should I send these perms, without transformation to the client, so that the React code can generate the navbar on front side.

What bother me the most here is that permissions name won't have the same name as admin pages path. If I choose the second solution, I'll have to write the path to the admin pages for each authorisation somewhere in the code like

```js
const getPermissionsRelatedPath = function (perm) {
    swith(perm) {
        case 'perm1': return '/admin/path1;
        case 'perm2': return '/admin/other_path;
        //etc...
    }
}
```

I'm afraid that's a security problem

Another thing to consider is that, in the long term, I'd like to show or hide the delete data button depending on whether or not the user has permissions, which seems a bit complicated with the first method.

Comment: "*I'll have to write the path to the admin pages for each authorisation*" - shouldn't it be the other way round, writing which permission a particular admin page needs? Multiple pages/paths could require the same permission.

Comment: I don't get what this has to do with feature flags.

Comment: "*I'm afraid that's a security problem*" - there is no security problem if your backend is implemented correctly and checks the permissions for every resource. The frontend doesn't really matter. There's a potential usability problem if the UI doesn't match your permissions (lacking buttons/pages that you need, or showing buttons/pages that won't work), and there's a potential code maintainability problem if your UI structure doesn't match your permission model, and if the resource<->permission mapping code needs to be duplicated on backend and frontend.

Comment: @Bergi Sure I will write the permissions needs for admin pages on server side. But I'd also like the user to see only the options to which they have access permissions in their navbar. I don't want the "Staff Users" option to be displayed if he doesn't have access permissions to the page. Isn't that what feature flags are all about?

Comment: No, a [feature flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle) is a configuration setting that enables or disables a whole part of your application code. It's generally per deployment/installation, not per user (although you can muddy the waters by having different users run different variants of your application).

Comment: you're right, I edited the question ! I'm sorry ! Also I wanted to ask about that *"if your UI structure doesn't match your permission model, and if the resource<->permission mapping code needs to be duplicated on backend and frontend."*. What's the solution here, should I only write this mapping function on server side and then process data before sending it to the client ?

Comment: How your permission model and your (admin) UI are structured depends on the application (requirements), I can't give generic advice there. You'd need to provide a lot more details in the question. As for duplicating code, you can either do all the processing in the backend and have a thin client, or you can - given your backend is written in JS - share the code by putting it in a common package.